# My Site Won't Display Mobile @Media CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

For my site TheExpeditioner.com I have added mobile specific CSS beginning with:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
```

I have also included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the header.

However, my site will not display the mobile CSS in mobile devices. Am I missing something? Is this something to do with Wordpress and/or plugins?

Comment: can you also add sample code or a link? if i can take a look then maybe i can help you.

Comment: Here is the CSS:

http://theexpeditioner.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ColormaticTheme/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is 1 thing that my eye caught for now

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 768px) 
and (max-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
```

its at line 1499, and there is no closing bracket.